# Orthogonal projection problem linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is:

Let $w = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix} $

Find the matrix P that gives the orthogonal projection of a vector
$x ∈ R^3$ onto the subspace $W = Span(w)$. Determine the eigenvalues
and eigenvectors of P and describe them in relation to W.

The closest I have got to an answer that makes some kind of sense to me is the projection matrix formula
$ P = A(A^TA)^{-1}A^{T} $ Which if I write $ A = w $
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}(\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix})^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} $$   $$P = \frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone explain what is happening if this is true. Or is it the wrong way of doing it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it should be$$P=A\left(A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T,$$but, yes, it is equal to$$\frac13\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}.\tag1$$The eigenvalues of this matrix are $1$ and $0$ (and that's what one would expect from a projection matrix). One of its eigenvectors (corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$) is $w$ itself. The eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ are those (non-null) vectors which are orthogonal to $w$.

You can also get the matrix $(1)$ by computing $P(e_i)$, where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb R$. For each $v\in\Bbb R^3$, $P(v)=\frac1{\|w\|^2}(v.w)w$. So,$$P(1,0,0)=P(0,1,0)=P(0,0,1)=\frac13(1,1,1).$$

Comment: Thank you. The second way of doing it as you write seems a little more intuitive!

Comment: That's what I think too.

Answer (score 1):

Although your $P$ is correct, it is not needed to figure out the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $P$.

Because $P$ is a projection onto (the span of) $(1,1,1)$, the vector $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $1$. Everything that is perpendicular to $(1,1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $P$ with an eigenvalue of $0$. So, for instance, take $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ as a basis for the eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$.